# Hot to create pandas DataFrame from the list of arrays?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data structured as follows:

```
listOfArrays = 
    [array([3, 21, 28]),
     array([13, 14, 2, 29]),
     array([2, 21])]
```

I need to convert it into a pandas DataFrame with 1 column:

```
col1
3
21
28
13
14
2
29
2
21
```

Currently I create pandas DataFrames one by one:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lisOfLists[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lisOfLists[1])
...
```

and the I concatenate them using `pd.concat`.

Is there any shorter approach?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(listOfArrays), columns=['col1'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame({"col1": np.concatenate(listOfArrays, axis=0)})
   col1
0     3
1    21
2    28
3    13
4    14
5     2
6    29
7     2
8    21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehensions:

```py
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd

listOfArrays = [array([3, 21, 28]), array([13, 14, 2, 29]), array([2, 21])]

df = pd.concat([pd.Series(array) for array in listOfArrays])
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [itertool chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd
import itertools

list_of_arrays = [array([3, 21, 28]), array([13, 14, 2, 29]), array([2, 21])]
df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_arrays), columns=['col1'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
   col1
0     3
1    21
2    28
3    13
4    14
5     2
6    29
7     2
8    21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just load the list into a dataframe and then use `melt`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(listOfArrays).melt()[['value']]
```

via `stack` and `reset_index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(listOfArrays).stack().reset_index()[[0]]
```

or can also use itertools chain:

```
from itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list(chain(*listOfArrays))})
```